Experiencing delays in network connection execution
Experiencing delays in desktop connection execution.
After each  boot it takes considerable time BEFORE
any network access is actually running.
This is NOT a network issue - it goes away after about a minute.
I have been advised to "cleanup " any recently used files in settings.
It sort of temporary helps.
This can be observed  in little window ( status ?) in upper left corner - the text is flashing when the connection is "in progress".
Sometime I can get connected to a site, but any mouse clicks takes no effect - is another result of this problem.
I am using 22.04.4 and this seems to be getting worse with each "update".
I am not interested in opinions ,upgrade  or "me too" comments.
Do not waste your time.
PS
Not sure if this is related, but my  " FireFox" is always sorry because it cannot "restore " previous state. ALWAYS, but it can be restored manually.
I am asking for a solution, no AI bot comments, please.

With the rude comments in your question do not expect an answer.
